# Question on Eilenberg-Watts theorem

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, adjoint-functors

I'm not sure if this is a research level question, but:

Let $F:Rep_A \to Rep_B$ be an exact cocomplete functor between representation categories of finite dimensional $k$ algebras, where $k$ has charecteristic zero and is algebraically closed. By Eilenberg-Watts $F$ has both left and right adjoint. Are they naturally isomorphic?

Comment: You want $F$ to be cocontinuous, right? Otherwise I don't know what Eilenberg-Watts theorem you mean. Is there a classification of arbitrary exact functors?

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Suppose $F=-\otimes_AM$, where $M$ is a finite dimensional $B$-$A$-bimodule that is projective as a left $A$-module (so that $F$ is exact).

The right adjoint is $\text{Hom}_B(M,-)$. But unless $M$ is also projective as a right $B$-module this is not right exact, and so can’t be a left adjoint.

So, for example, take $A=k$ and $M$ any non-projective $B$-module.

Comment: Thx! Okay, so but at least in the case where $B \subseteq A$ and $F$ is the forgetful functor, this should be true, right?

Comment: @BipolarMinds No. In that case $F=-\otimes_AA$, regarding $A$ as an $A$-$B$-bimodule via left multiplication by $A$ and right multiplication by $B$. So the right adjoint $\text{Hom}_B(A,-)$ is only right exact if $A$ is projective as a right $B$-module.